# Scala parser combinator with recursive structures

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner with Scala, and now learning Scala parser combinator, writing "MiniLogicParser", a mini parser for propositional logic formula. I am successful for parsing it partly, but can not convert to case class. I tried some codes like below.

```
import java.io._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

sealed trait Bool[+A]
case object True extends Bool[Nothing]
case class Var[A](label: A) extends Bool[A]
case class Not[A](child: Bool[A]) extends Bool[A]
case class And[A](children: List[Bool[A]]) extends Bool[A]

object LogicParser extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = true

  def formula = ( TRUE | not | and | textdata )
  def TRUE  = "TRUE"
  def not : Parser[_] = NEG ~ formula  ^^ {case ( "!"  ~ formula) => Not(formula)}
  def and : Parser[_] = LPARENTHESIS ~ formula ~ opt(CONJUNCT ~ formula) ~ RPARENTHESIS
  def NEG = "!"
  def CONJUNCT = "&&"
  def LPARENTHESIS = '('
  def RPARENTHESIS = ')'
  def textdata = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+".r

  def apply(input: String): Either[String, Any] = parseAll(formula, input) match {
      case Success(logicData, next)        => Right(logicData)
      case NoSuccess(errorMessage, next) => Left(s"$errorMessage on line ${next.pos.line} on column ${next.pos.column}")
    }
}
```

but, the compilation failed with the following error message

```
[error] ... MiniLogicParser.scala:15 type mismatch;  
[error]  found : Any 
[error]  required: Bool[?]  
[error]  def not : Parser[_] = NEG ~ formula  ^^ {case ( "!"  ~ formula) => Not(formula)}
```

I can partly understand the error message; i.e., it means for line 15 where I tried to convert the result of parsing to case class, type mismatch is occurring. However, I do not understand how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted your parser a little bit.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
sealed trait Bool[+A]
case object True extends Bool[Nothing]
case class Var[A](label: A) extends Bool[A]
case class Not[A](child: Bool[A]) extends Bool[A]
case class And[A](l: Bool[A], r: Bool[A]) extends Bool[A]


object LogicParser extends RegexParsers with App {
  override def skipWhitespace = true

  def NEG = "!"
  def CONJUNCT = "&&"
  def LP = '('
  def RP = ')'

  def TRUE = literal("TRUE") ^^ { case _ => True }
  def textdata = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+".r ^^ { case x => Var(x) }

  def formula: Parser[Bool[_]] = textdata | and | not | TRUE
  def not = NEG ~ formula ^^ { case n ~ f => Not(f) }
  def and = LP ~> formula ~ CONJUNCT ~ formula <~ RP ^^ { case f1 ~ c ~ f2 => And(f1, f2) }

  def apply(input: String): Either[String, Any] = parseAll(formula, input) match {
    case Success(logicData, next) => Right(logicData)
    case NoSuccess(errorMessage, next) => Left(s"$errorMessage on line ${next.pos.line} on column ${next.pos.column}")
  }

  println(apply("TRUE"))            // Right(Var(TRUE))
  println(apply("(A && B)"))        // Right(And(Var(A),Var(B)))
  println(apply("((A && B) && C)")) // Right(And(And(Var(A),Var(B)),Var(C)))
  println(apply("!(A && !B)"))      // Right(Not(And(Var(A),Not(Var(B)))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The child of the `Not`-node is of type `Bool`. In line 15 however, `formula`, the value that you want to pass to `Not`'s `apply` method, is of type `Any`. You can restrict the extractor (i.e., the `case`-statement) to only match values of `formula` that are of type `Bool` by adding the type information after a colon:

```
case ( "!"  ~ (formula: Bool[_]))
```

Hence, the `not` method would look like this:

```
def not : Parser[_] = NEG ~ formula  ^^ {case ( "!"  ~ (formula: Bool[_])) => Not(formula)}
```

However, now, e.g., `"!TRUE"` does not match anymore, because `"TRUE"` is not yet of type `Bool`. This can be fixed by extending your parser to convert the string to a `Bool`, e.g.,

```
def TRUE  = "TRUE" ^^ (_ => True)
```